# Wrapper script to list sourced/executed files

Tags: shell, trace

Is it possible to write a command which runs `my.sh` and *prints every path sourced or executed by this script recursively* - That is, *without altering the original code* at all? The idea is to verify which files are actually used for a specific execution path, without time-consuming and error-prone manual tracing.

For example:

```
$ > my.sh cat <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
. ./foo.sh
EOF
$ > foo.sh cat <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
./bar.sh
EOF
$ > bar.sh cat <<'EOF'
#!/bin/sh
echo bar
EOF
$ chmod u+x my.sh bar.sh
$ magic command
[...]
./my.sh
./foo.sh
./bar.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick:

```
$ strace -fe open ./my.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | \
grep --only-matching '^\(\[pid\s\+[0-9]*\] \)\?open("[^"]\+' | \
grep --only-matching '".*' | \
cut --characters 2-
```

In other words, trace the execution and print `open` calls, swap stdout and stderr, then format the result to strip away irrelevant text.

It does print some library paths as well, which is not really a big issue:

```
/etc/ld.so.cache
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
./my.sh
./foo.sh
/etc/ld.so.cache
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
./bar.sh
```

Some remaining questions:

- Is there some way to reliably distinguish between shell and library paths? The latter seems to be possible since all the library references use the [`O_CLOEXEC`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) option, while none of the shell references do.
- Is it possible to distinguish between sourced and executed paths?
- Are there demonstrable corner cases where this command will fail?

Comment: One minute too early... :-o